# Searching Large String for file path. Return filepath + filename

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've got a little project where I’m trying to download a series of wallpapers from a web page.  I'm new to python.

I'm using the `urllib` library, which is returning a long string of web page data which includes

```
<a href="http://website.com/wallpaper/filename.jpg">
```

I know that every filename I need to download has

```
'http://website.com/wallpaper/'
```

How can i search the page source for this portion of text, and return the rest of the image link, ending with "*.jpg" extension?

```
r'http://website.com/wallpaper/ xxxxxx .jpg'
```

I'm thinking if I could format a regular expression with the xxxx portion not being evaluated? Just check for the path, and the .jpg extension.  Then return the whole string once a match is found

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You can use `regex` but don't . Perhaps `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is pretty convenient for this sort of thing.

```
import re
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

jpg_regex = re.compile('\.jpg$')
site_regex = re.compile('website\.com\/wallpaper\/')

pool = urllib3.PoolManager()
request = pool.request('GET', 'http://your_website.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request)

jpg_list = list(soup.find_all(name='a', attrs={'href':jpg_regex}))
site_list = list(soup.find_all(name='a', attrs={'href':site_regex}))

result_list = map(lambda a: a.get('href'), jpg_list and site_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Two votes for beautifulsoup, I guess I need to check it out.  I came across it in my google-fu, but didn't know exactly how to use it

Answer (score 3):

I think a very basic regex will do.
Like:

```
(http:\/\/website\.com\/wallpaper\/[\w\d_-]*?\.jpg)
```

and if you use `$1`this will return the whole String  .

And if you use

```
(http:\/\/website\.com\/wallpaper\/([\w\d_-]*?)\.jpg)
```

then `$1` will give the whole string and `$2` will give the file name only.

Note: escaping (`\/`) is  language dependent so use what is supported by python.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regular expression against HTML.

Instead, use a HTML parsing library.

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a library for parsing HTML and [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) is a built-in module for fetching URLs

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

content = urllib2.urlopen('http://website.com/wallpaper/index.html').read()
html = bs(content)
links = [] # an empty list

for link in html.find_all('a'):
   href = link.get('href')
   if '/wallpaper/' in href:
      links.append(href)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Two votes for beautifulsoup, I guess I need to check it out.  I came across it in my google-fu, but didn't know exactly how to use it

Answer (score 2):

Search for the "http://website.com/wallpaper/" substring in url and then check for ".jpg" in url, as shown below:

```
domain = "http://website.com/wallpaper/"
url = str("your URL")
format = ".jpg"
for domain in url and format in url:
    //do something
```